# Creating http based authentication

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, authentication

Is there any open source libraries for creating http based authentication like flickr and remember the milk?

Answer (score 0):

http://openid.net/ is nice for public facing sites. Same sort of thing stackoverflow uses.

Otherwise it'll depend on your web development framework.

Comment: I'm creating a simple service that should use some kind of api key so it's not a specific username/password authentication i'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You'll be signing requests. Any OpenID or OAuth library will have code which does that - if not a separate library, something you can rip out, even though you're not using the protocol flow.

Alternately, there's demo code for Amazon AWS clients in their developer docs which also signs requests with API keys and timestamps.  It's the same process on the client or server side - comparing a hash with the original - so you'll probably just have to translate their request model to whatever your framework uses.

Neither of these are exactly what you're asking for, but it's a start.